# for loop problem in python 3.5 for loop not print dictionary keys in sequence

Tags: python, tkinter

here is my python 3.5 code i want to make theme list with **color-ColorName** format.....Colors print sequentially but Name interchange(color's name not print sequentially)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font,colorchooser,filedialog,messagebox
import os

#window formation
main_application = tk.Tk()
main_application.geometry("1200x800")
main_application.title("Speak with Me")

main_menu = tk.Menu()

#theme menu icons
lightdefault_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = "icon/lightdefault.png")
lightplus_theme = tk.PhotoImage(file = "icon/lightplus.png")
dark_theme = tk.PhotoImage(file = "icon/dark.png")
red_theme = tk.PhotoImage(file = "icon/red.png")
monokai_theme = tk.PhotoImage(file = "icon/monokai.png")
nightblue_theme = tk.PhotoImage(file = "icon/nightblue.png")

color_theme = tk.Menu(main_menu,tearoff=False)
main_menu.add_cascade(label = "Theme",menu=color_theme)

color_icons=(lightdefault_icon,lightplus_theme,dark_theme,red_theme,monokai_theme,nightblue_theme)

color_dict = {
        'Light Default' : ('#000000',"#ffffff"),
        'Light Plus'  : ('#474747','#e0e0e0'),
        'Dark' : ('#c4c4c4','#2d2d2d'),
        'Red'  : ('#2d2d2d','#ffe8e8'),
        'Monokai' : ('#d3b774','#474747'),
        'Night Blue'  : ('#ededed','#6b9dc2')

    }

count = 0
for key in color_dict:
    color_theme.add_radiobutton(label=key,image=color_icons[count],compound=tk.LEFT)
    count+=1
 
main_application.config(menu=main_menu)


main_application.mainloop()
```

here is my output

[image]

Comment: Try a later Python version. I believe dicts maintain insertion order from 3.6 (and more formally guaranteed in 3.7).

Comment: Use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to retain insertion order prior to 3.6